# SES VPC endpoint not working with default service hostname

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, amazon-vpc

I have created a VPC endpoint for SES with Private DNS names enabled.  My VPC also has DNS Hostnames and DNS Support enabled as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-interface.html#vpce-private-dns).  The endpoint has a security group allowing access from the VPC to ports 25, 465 and 587 and it is in the same subnet as a linux ec2 instance that I am testing with.

Using python to send an SMTP email from the ec2 instance, if I use the default smtp endpoint `email-smtp.region.amazonaws.com` the source IP address listed in the SES notification is the public IP address of the instance.  If I use the endpoint specific hostname `vpce-1234-abc.email-smtp.region.vpce.amazonaws.com`, the source IP address shows up as as an unknown 10.0.x.x address that is not part of my VPC but I guess is an internal AWS IP?

Are there any extra steps required to get the SES VPC endpoint working with the default smtp endpoint?

Telnet output for each hostname:

```
> telnet email-smtp.region.amazonaws.com 587
Trying 52.220.82.145...
Connected to email-smtp.region.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-d-abc abc123
451 4.4.2 Timeout waiting for data from client.

> telnet vpce-00649432966443d57-5oqa8t62.email-smtp.region.vpce.amazonaws.com 587
Trying 172.x.x.x...
Connected to vpce-123-abc.email-smtp.region.vpce.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-d-abc abc123
451 4.4.2 Timeout waiting for data from client.
```

Comment: I know there's a similar issue with new VPC endpoints where the public DNS doesn't properly route to the VPC endpoint. However, this is usually resolved by specifying the region (so email-smtp.region.amazonaws.com). Can you share telnet results from using this endpoint as well as the others?

Comment: Ah now that is a simple test... updated question.

Comment: I'm assuming you're replacing "region" for actual region right. Either way, your best bet might be to explicitly define the endpoint, or get in touch with AWS support and see if they plan on adding this capability for the public DNS